# Dont know whats creating bottom scroll bar

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes

I'm working on a theme for wordpress here http://mhutchinson.me.uk/ but a scroll bar is being added to the bottom of the webpage saying that the body content is wider than the page.

But I cant figure out whats pushing the content out. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks,
Megan

Comment: In which browser exactly are you experiencing this problem? I've tested on IE9, 8, 7, Chrome and FF and none of these show what you said.

Comment: I don't know what causing a problem, but I can see that you are using wrong Bootstrap "row" and "span" classes. Inside div with "row" class ypu can have only span classes in sum of 12. Example: Inside row class you can have [span2, span8, span2], or [span6, span6] etc. (my english is soooo bad, but you can check this link to see what I mean http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html)

Comment: My boot strap spans only add up to 12, im using [span4, span4, span4] and [span8, span4]. Where am i using over 12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be Your problem:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" id="f1830c0ce6ba962" name="f323631050eb616" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; height: 240px; width: 575px;" class="FB_UI_Hidden" src="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?api_key=153185341443233&amp;app_id=153185341443233&amp;channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D9%23cb%3Df4145651077ece%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fmhutchinson.me.uk%252Ffb320d27f95db6%26domain%3Dmhutchinson.me.uk%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;client_id=153185341443233&amp;display=none&amp;domain=mhutchinson.me.uk&amp;locale=en_US&amp;origin=1&amp;redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D9%23cb%3Df24fe177267a76a%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fmhutchinson.me.uk%252Ffb320d27f95db6%26domain%3Dmhutchinson.me.uk%26relation%3Dparent%26frame%3Df1830c0ce6ba962&amp;response_type=token%2Csigned_request%2Ccode&amp;sdk=joey"></iframe>
```

You need to make this iframe width smaller.

Comment: Which part in particular as I have tried messing around with individual divs within the Iframe including the iframe itself and the scroll bar is still there.

Comment: In style of this iframe You need to change 'width:575px' to for example 'width:275px'

Answer (score 0):

If you just care about getting rid of the scrollbar, you can hack it out by specifying the overflow or width of your `html` or `body` elements.

Comment: Yer if i set an overflow:hidden to the body it's fine. But I dont really want to add unnecessary code and would rather try and find whats causing it

Answer (score 0):

Well if you really can't figure it out start with this before all of the other CSS:
http://www.cssreset.com/

Comment: Its on a Macbook Pro in Firefox